# VBA: Scrape dynamically created webpage?

Tags: vba, web-scraping

Trying to use VBA to scrape some product pages with 30 products per page. If you inspect the page in dev tools, the elements I need are all in span tags with straightforward class names; "part-number", "price", etc. There will be one for each product on the page, and then one empty one. But if you Ctrl + U and look at the source code, only the empty one is there. So if you look in dev tools there are 31 span tags with class "part-number", 30 populated ones and one empty. But if you look at the source code, only the empty one is there.

If I attempt to do something like...

```
For x = 0 to 29
    Debug.Print "Part number = " & ie.document.getElementsByClassName("part-number")(x).innerText
Next x
```

...it returns one blank value and then errors off with "Object variable or With block variable not set."

Pretty sure what's happening here is that the source code being served up by the server only includes the one blank span tag for each class, and then the rest of the HTML is being dynamically created by Javascript or whatever, but VBA is only attempting to scrape the original source code.

Any way I can get it to scrape the DOM after being rendered instead?

Comment: My only experience with VBA web scraping was to download the page as a text file (using Open fileName For Input As #fileNo) and then parse it by tags.  It was ugly, and it was a pain in the behind, but it worked.  I used to scrape my ebay sales into a database for easier tracking, but every time ebay changed their code I had to tweak my Access file so I gave up.

Comment: Do you have an example URL?

Comment: If you can provide the URL, a different approach might be found to scrape your part numbers.

Comment: Since you show very little code we can only guess what's going on, but it seems likely you're not waiting for the dynamic page to be constructed (it's not enough to check readystate or similar) so you end up working with the "as delivered" source and not the "constructed after load" source.  Try adding a Wait before grabbing the span elements.

Comment: Obviously the page uses AJAX. You may do that in more efficient manner, without using IE DOM and loading the page. Examine XHRs on Developer Tools Network tab, find the relevant response containing the necessary data, create VBA code to reproduce such XHR, parse it and extract the data.